# Obscure religious expression

Tags: expressions, religion

菩提心をおこすこと、かならず慮知心をもちいる。

It's something about enlightenment and Buddha thing, but I can't find any English equivalent to 慮知心, not to mention the whole expression.

"Enlightenment through empathy"?

Comment: [Here you come](http://www.dogen-shobogenzo.com/hotubodaisin1.html). Explanations are in normal font. Bold lines use old grammar.

Comment: On the other hand, I find a certain touch of irony in having おこす, かならず and もちいる in かな while 菩提心 and 慮知心 walk their ways in 漢字.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving the two pieces of jargon as-is, this archaic Japanese sentence can be translated as "To make/cause/realize 菩提心, one always uses 慮知心."

菩提心 is explained in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhicitta).

慮知心 seems to be much rarer, and it's a word introduced by [道元](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C5%8Dgen) as one of the "three types of 心" (mind/heart). To put it very plainly, 慮知心 is 思慮分別する心 ("mind that reasons and thinks deeply"), according to [this](http://seesaawiki.jp/w/turatura/d/%CE%B8%C3%CE%BF%B4).

So I think the whole sentence roughly means "To try to achieve the enlightenment of Buddha, you must exert your reasoning skills." or something like that. But 慮知心 seems to have a much deeper meaning to Buddhism experts, so you may want to ask about this word in [Buddhism Stack Exchange](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/).